# Spring Admin Server on Kubernetes doesn't register new pods

Tags: java, kubernetes, monitoring, spring-boot-admin

I deployed Spring Boot Admin on an Azure Kubernetes Cluster. At first I get the pods of my app displayed as "UP". After restarting the deployment of the pods all pods are down and the new pods aren't recognized by Spring Boot Admin server. Is there anything I am missing?

[Pods are UP as they should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZjCS.png)

[New pods don't get registered and old are still on the dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQMyh.png)

My application.yml

```
spring:
  boot:
    admin:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
      monitor:
        status-interval: 3s
        status-lifetime: 3s
  application:
    name: monitoring-server
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      discovery:
        primary-port-name: health
        enabled: true
        service-labels:
          spring.boot: middleware
      enabled: true
```

Main Class with annotations

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAdminServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableScheduling
public class MonitoringApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MonitoringApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Added dependencies

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Edit:

```
spring boot version: 2.6.6
spring boot admin version: 2.6.3
spring cloud version: 2021.0.1
```

Comment: Did you get this to work? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I abandoned the problem. In hindsight the problem might be that I didn't configure any probes (health/readiness/liveliness)

Comment: I am having the same issue, even with readiness and liveness probes

Answer (score 0):

Please try to activate the reloads.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      reload:
        enabled: true
```

Comment: tried it and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the dependency `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-kubernetes-fabric8-discovery` instead of `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-all`?
This is where I found it: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/1788
And according to this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/issues/1042, it should be solved with Spring Cloud 2022.0.1.